# tesseract 3.01 actual_tessdata_num_entries_ <= TESSDATA_NUM_ENTRIES

Tags: c++, ocr, tesseract, magick++

I'm building tesseract 3.01 and magick++ into a program because the command line versions were too slow. getting everything compiled correctly took forever but finally I get no errors in my compiler, but as soon as I go to run my console app I get

```
PS C:\Users\sirus\Documents\Visual Studio 2013\Projects\ConsoleApplication4\Release> .\ConsoleApplication4.exe
first command
actual_tessdata_num_entries_ <= TESSDATA_NUM_ENTRIES:Error:Assert failed:in file ..\ccutil\tessdatamanager.cpp, line 48
PS C:\Users\sirus\Documents\Visual Studio 2013\Projects\ConsoleApplication4\Release> l
```

searching for this online shows that this is what happens when you have to incorrect language data, but I have tesseract 3.01 and the tesseract 3.01 language data downloaded directly from their google code site.

I'm using visual studio 2013 on windows 8.1 building 32 bit /MD

here is a sample of my source

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <string>
#include <iostream>               
#include <iomanip>
#include <locale>
#include <sstream>
#include <string> 
#include <Magick++.h>
#include "baseapi.h"
#include "allheaders.h"
using namespace Magick;
using namespace std;
using namespace tesseract;
#define MaxRGB ((Magick::Quantum)65545)
tesseract::TessBaseAPI tess;



string cmd = "";
string cmd2 = "";


void img_split(){
    string tesseract = "\"C:\\Program Files (x86)\\Tesseract-OCR\\tesseract.exe\" text/";
    int rect_y = 141;
    string del = "del /s /q text\\*";
    system(del.c_str());
    for (int x = 1; x < 40; x++){
        rect_y += 19;
        Image image;
        image.read("source.jpg");
        Magick::Image* mImage;
        Image sub_image(image);
        mImage = &sub_image;
        //mImage->write("test.jpg");


        sub_image.chop(Geometry(1481, rect_y));
        sub_image.crop(Geometry(220, 17));

        sub_image.quantizeColorSpace(GRAYColorspace);
        sub_image.quantizeColors(2);
        sub_image.quantizeDither(false);
        sub_image.quantize();
        sub_image.scale(Geometry(2200,170));
        sub_image.antiAlias();
        sub_image.compressType(Magick::NoCompression);


        //const unsigned char* imagedata = (unsigned char*)mImage;
        //tess.SetImage(imagedata, 2200, 170, 1, 17300);
        //tess.Recognize(0);
        //const char* out = tess.GetUTF8Text();
        //cout << "\n\nno idea if this will work: " << out << endl;


        sub_image.write("text/" + static_cast<ostringstream*>(&(ostringstream() << x))->str() + ".gif");
        //cmd2 = tesseract + static_cast<ostringstream*>(&(ostringstream() << x))->str() + ".png text/" + static_cast<ostringstream*>(&(ostringstream() << x))->str();
        //tesseract_ocr(x);
    }

}

int main(int argc, char **argv)
{
    cout << "first command\n";
    //tess.Init(argv[0], "eng", tesseract::OEM_DEFAULT);
    tess.Init(*argv, "eng");
    tess.SetPageSegMode(tesseract::PSM_AUTO);
    cout << "\ntest" << endl;
    InitializeMagick(*argv);
    //img_split();

    return 0;
}
```

bonus points if you can tell me how to correctly pass the image in sub_image to tesseract's setimage function (because i'm pretty sure what I have wont be right either)

Answer (score 0):

> actual_tessdata_num_entries <= TESSDATA_NUM_ENTRIES:Error:Assert
>   failed:in file ..\ccutil\tessdatamanager.cpp, line 55

If you get error during running tesseract, please check if you use correct version of traineddata (e.g. 3.00 with 3.01). You can not use 3.01 traineddata with tesseract 3.00.

---

To sum it up you just need to get the traineddata for your version.. or don't even mess with the traineddata and use the ones that it comes with when you download it.

Check out this link below for the solution.

[https://code.google.com/p/tesseract-ocr/wiki/FAQ#actual_tessdata_num_entries_<=_TESSDATA_NUM_ENTRIES:Error:Ass](https://code.google.com/p/tesseract-ocr/wiki/FAQ#actual_tessdata_num_entries_%3C=_TESSDATA_NUM_ENTRIES:Error:Ass)